# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String exclamationmark

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, nsuserdefaults

I am generating a QRCode with name, email and phone number of user which are entered in registration form. In RegistrationVC, I have used userdefaults to save all these 3 fields.  Now in my QRGenerate VC, with the help of user default I want to generate QR code, but throwing an error

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String!".

I am passing all three keys to a string (i.e.qrgeneratestring) and generating QRCodes.

```
phoneKeyValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "phoneKey")
nameKeyValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "nameKey")
emailidKeyValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "emailIDKey")
var qrgeneratestring = nameKeyValue + emailidKeyValue + phoneKeyValue


    if qrgeneratestring.isEmpty == false{
        let ciImageFromQRCode = generateQRCodeFromString(strQR: qrgeneratestring)
        let scaleX = (imgViewQRCode.frame.size.width / ciImageFromQRCode.extent.size.width)
        let scaleY = (imgViewQRCode.frame.size.height / ciImageFromQRCode.extent.size.height)
        let imgTransformed = ciImageFromQRCode.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY))
        imgViewQRCode.image = UIImage(ciImage: imgTransformed)

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Note that if you create an image straight from a CIImage you won't be able to convert that UIImage to data later on using PNG or JPEG representation methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string(forKey` returns an optional, you need to unwrap the three values and you have to declare the variables as non-optional

```
var phoneKeyValue = ""
var nameKeyValue = ""
var emailidKeyValue = ""

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
phoneKeyValue = defaults.string(forKey: "phoneKey") ?? ""
nameKeyValue = defaults.string(forKey: "nameKey") ?? ""
emailidKeyValue = defaults.string(forKey: "emailIDKey") ?? ""
```

Comment: thank you for your inputs, but same error is showing, for       var qrgeneratestring = nameKeyValue + emailidKeyValue + phoneKeyValue                        Error is=>Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String!'

Comment: Thank You Vadian for quick help. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

The UserDefaults method `string(forKey:...)` returns an optional - that is a value that can either be of the type String, or nil.

You need to unwrap the optional, either using exclamation mark `!` or using the coalesence operator `??`. This depends on whether you know the value can't be nil (so you use exclamation mark) or you provide a default value when the optional is a nil value.

In this case I would use:

```
phoneKeyValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "phoneKey") ?? ""
nameKeyValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "nameKey") ?? ""
emailidKeyValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "emailIDKey") ?? ""
var qrgeneratestring = nameKeyValue + emailidKeyValue + phoneKeyValue
```

Comment: You could also use `if let` or `guard` to safely unwrap the optionals.